# ¿Como declarar un arreglo con media SoundPlayer en C#?

Tags: c#, array, windows-forms

Estoy haciendo un proyecto para reproducir canciones, pero para almacenar las canciones tengo que declarar cada cancion en una variable diferente de esta forma

```
SoundPlayer variable = new SoundPlayer("Cancion.wav");
SoundPlayer variable2 = new SoundPlayer("Cancion.wav");
```

Entonces lo que me interesa es almacenar las canciones en una sola variable, para poder recorrerla con un for, mas o menos de esta manera

```
SoundPlayer[] variable = new SoundPlayer [1] {"Cancion1.wav", "Cancion2.wav"};
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inicializa los objetos en una lista si son estaticos:

```
List<SoundPlayer> sonidos = new List<SoundPlayer>{
   new SoundPlayer("Cancion.wav"),
   new SoundPlayer("OtraCancion.wav") ... //etc
};
```

O Inicializa la lista con el método `.Add(T)` si son dinámicos:

```
var sonidos = new List<SoundPlayer>();
//code y más code
sonidos.Add(new SoundPlayer("Cancion.wav"));
```

Finalmente puedes manejar los objetos de tipo `SoundPlayer` como un arreglo, según el indice o posición.

```
 SoundPlayer var1 = sonidos[0];
 SoundPlayer var2 = sonidos[1];
 ...
```

Alternativamente con un array simple:

```
SoundPlayer[] array = {new SoundPlayer("Cancion1.wav"),new SoundPlayer("Cancion2.wav"), ...};
```

Recuerda que para crear nuevos objetos debes utilizar la palabra reservada `new` forzosamente.

Comment: No si, lo que quiero hacer es no tener que declararlo en varios, si no mas que nada, que en uno solo introducir todas las canciones

Comment: Edite mi respuesta, de la manera en que lo planteas en la pregunta es muy confusa, recuerda que para crear objetos nuevos utilizas `new` forzosamente, tambien a como se puede entender, puedes almacenar las canciones como un arreglo de `string` y luego pasarlo a un objeto `SoundPlayer`, recuerda que no puedes mezclar peras con manzanas, en este caso, `SoundPlayer` con `string`.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, me es de mucha ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Podrias definir una lista como ser

```
List<SoundPlayer> listaCanciones = new List<SoundPlayer>();
listaCanciones.Add(new SoundPlayer("Cancion.wav"));
listaCanciones.Add(new SoundPlayer("Cancion2.wav"));
```

entonces puedes iterarla usando

```
foreach(var cancion in listaCanciones){
  cancion.Play();
}
```

Bueno en realidad esto es solo un ejemplo, no digo que en un loop dieras play a cada cancion, pero se entiende la idea que al iterar acceder a cada archivo que tengas en la lista

Comment: No si, lo que quiero hacer es no tener que declararlo en varios, si no mas que nada, que en uno solo introducir todas las canciones

Comment: ehh por eso usas la lista, solo declaras una unica variable donde pones como item cada cancion, sino es esto entonces edita la pregunta y explicate mejor

Comment: La voy a editar